# Symfony2 login FOS UserBundle in functional tests

Tags: unit-testing, symfony, phpunit, fosuserbundle

How to login inside tests to be able to do user-specific actions?

Answer (score 5):

Actually, the authentication must be done like a real user do it. In that case, you have to know the plain password and fill the login form

```php
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase;
class XXX extends WebTestCase {
  public function testUserLogin() {

   $client = static::createClient();
   $crawler = $client->request('GET', '/login');

   $form = $crawler->selectButton('_submit')->form(array(
     '_username'  => 'user',
     '_password'  => 'pa$$word',
   ));

   $client->submit($form);
   $crawler = $client->followRedirect(); // "/" page

   // if credentials were correct, you should be logged in and ready to test your app
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The existing answers to this question have been helpful, but none of them solved my problem directly. I'm using Symfony 2.3.

Here is my solution:

```
<?php

namespace CDE\TestBundle\Base;

use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase;
use Symfony\Component\BrowserKit\Cookie;
use Symfony\Component\BrowserKit\CookieJar;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\MockFileSessionStorage;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\UsernamePasswordToken;

class BaseUserTest extends WebTestCase {

    protected $client;
    protected $container;
    protected $storage;
    protected $session;
    protected $user;
    protected $cookieJar;
    protected $cookie;
    protected $token;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->client = static::createClient();
        $this->container = $this->client->getContainer();
        $this->storage = new MockFileSessionStorage(__dir__.'/../../../../app/cache/test/sessions');
        $this->session = new Session($this->storage);

    }

    public function getUserManager() {
        return $this->container->get('cde_user.manager.user');

    }

    public function getSecurityManager() {
        return $this->container->get('fos_user.security.login_manager');

    }

    public function getUser($role = null) {
        if (!isset($this->user)) {
            $user = $this->getUserManager()->loadByUsername('user');

            if (isset($user)) {
                $this->user = $user;
            } else {
                $this->user = $this->getUserManager()->create();

                $this->user->setEnabled(true);
                $this->user->setUsername('user');
                $this->user->setEmail('user@quiver.is');
                $this->user->setPlainPassword('user');
                $this->getUserManager()->updatePassword($this->user);
                if (isset($role)) {
                    $this->user->addRole($role);
                }
                $this->getUserManager()->add($this->user);
            }

        }

        return $this->user;
    }

    public function logIn(User $user, Response $response) {
        $this->session->start();

        $this->cookie = new Cookie('MOCKSESSID', $this->storage->getId());
        $this->cookieJar = new CookieJar();
        $this->cookieJar->set($this->cookie);
        $this->token = new UsernamePasswordToken($user, 'user', 'main', $user->getRoles());
        $this->session->set('_security_main', serialize($this->token));


        $this->getSecurityManager()->loginUser(
            $this->container->getParameter('fos_user.firewall_name'),
            $user,
            $response
        );

        $this->session->save();
    }

    public function removeUser(User $user) {

    }
}
```

RestControllerTest.php

```
<?php

namespace CDE\ContentBundle\Tests\Controller;

use CDE\TestBundle\Base\BaseUserTest;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class RestControllerTest extends BaseUserTest
{
    protected $comment;

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->logIn($this->getUser('ROLE_ADMIN'), new Response());

    }

    public function getGalleryManager() {
        return $this->container->get('cde_content.manager.gallery');
    }

    public function getAWSManager() {
        return $this->container->get('cde_utility.manager.aws');
    }

    public function createGallery()
    {
        //        Copy test.jpeg into the web folder
        $filename = 'gallery/user-test.jpg';
        copy(__DIR__.'/../Mock/test.jpeg', __DIR__.'/../../../../../web/'.$filename);
        $this->getAWSManager()->copyGalleryFile($filename);


        $gallery = $this->getGalleryManager()->create();
        $gallery->setUser($this->getUser());
        $gallery->setFilename($filename);
        $gallery->setTitle('test gallery');
        $gallery->setDescription('test gallery description');
        $gallery->setMarked(false);
        $this->getGalleryManager()->add($gallery);
        $this->assertEquals($gallery->getMarked(), false);
    }

    public function createComment()
    {
        $galleries = $this->getGalleryManager()->findByUser($this->getUser());
        $gallery = $galleries[0];

        $client = static::createClient();
        $client->getCookieJar()->set($this->cookie);
//        $client = static::createClient(array(), new History(), $cookieJar);

        $crawler = $client->request('POST', 'api/createComment/'.$gallery->getId(), array(
            'comment' => 'testing testing 123',
            'marked' => 'false'
        ));

        $response = $client->getResponse();
        $this->comment = json_decode($response->getContent());
        $this->assertEquals($this->comment->comment, 'testing testing 123');
        $this->assertFalse($this->comment->marked);
        $this->assertEquals($response->getStatusCode(), 200);
    }

    public function getComment()
    {
        $client = static::createClient();

        $crawler = $client->request('GET', 'api/getComment/'.$this->comment->id);

        $response = $client->getResponse();
        $comment = json_decode($response->getContent());
        $this->assertEquals($comment->comment, 'testing testing 123');
        $this->assertFalse($comment->marked);
        $this->assertEquals($response->getStatusCode(), 200);

    }

    public function updateComment()
    {
        $client = static::createClient();

        $crawler = $client->request('GET', 'api/updateComment');
    }

    public function deleteComment()
    {
        $client = static::createClient();

        $crawler = $client->request('DELETE', 'api/deleteComment');
    }

    public function getComments()
    {
        $client = static::createClient();

        $crawler = $client->request('GET', 'api/getComments');
    }

    public function getGalleries()
    {
        $client = static::createClient();

        $crawler = $client->request('GET', 'api/getGalleries');
    }

    public function removeGallery() {
        $galleries = $this->getGalleryManager()->findByUser($this->getUser());
        foreach ($galleries as $gallery) {
            $this->getGalleryManager()->remove($gallery);
        }

    }

    public function testComments() {
        $this->createGallery();
        $this->createComment();
        $this->getComment();
        $this->updateComment();
        $this->deleteComment();
        $this->getComments();
        $this->getGalleries();
        $this->removeGallery();
    }

}
```

The code includes a base test class (`BaseUserTest.php`) that can be extended to easily log in users.

I've also included an example of how to use the base class in an example test (`RestControllerTest.php`). Notice this code block in RestControllerTest.php:

```
$client = static::createClient();
$client->getCookieJar()->set($this->cookie);
```

The idea behind BaseUserTest is that it can create it's own session, populate the session with the user, and then save the session to the file system using MockFileSessionStorage.

The tests themselves must then set the cookie on the client.

Comment: Hi, I like your solution.. Could you please paste in some of your security.yml configuration related to this.

Answer (score 2):

I know it is too late.. But in case someone needs this, I managed to logg a user in my unit test like this:

1- First Define a class which will give you access to services:

```
<?php
namespace Tests;

class ContainerAwareUnitTestCase extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    protected static $kernel;
    protected static $container;

    public static function setUpBeforeClass()
    {
        self::$kernel = new \AppKernel('dev', true);
        self::$kernel->boot();

        self::$container = self::$kernel->getContainer();
    }

    public function get($serviceId)
    {
        return self::$kernel->getContainer()->get($serviceId);
    }
}
```

2- Then declare a test as follow:

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Menu;

use Tests\ContainerAwareUnitTestCase;
use UserBundle\Entity\User;
use FOS\UserBundle\Security\UserProvider;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\UsernamePasswordToken;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContext;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Menu\MenuBuilder;

class MenuBuilderTest extends ContainerAwareUnitTestCase
{
    public function provider()
    {
        return array(array('/'));

    }

    /**
     * @dataProvider provider
     */
    public function testNoAuth($uri) 
    {
        /* @var $securityContext SecurityContext */
        $securityContext = $this->get('security.context');
        $userProvider = $this->get('fos_user.user_provider.username');
        $user = $userProvider->loadUserByUsername('alex');
        $token = new UsernamePasswordToken($user, null, 'main', array('ROLE_USER'));
        $securityContext->setToken($token);

        /* @var $menuBuilder MenuBuilder */
        $menuBuilder = $this->get('event_flow_analyser.menu_builder');

        $this->assertNotNull($menuBuilder);

        $request = new Request();
        $request->attributes->set('projectName', 'ucs');

        $menu = $menuBuilder->createMainMenu($request);

        $this->assertNotNull($menu);

        $this->assertNotNull($menu->getChild('Home'));
        $this->assertNotNull($menu->getChild('Profile'));

        $this->assertEquals(null, $menu->getChild('Projects'));
    }

}
```

This a complete exemple to test menuBuilder creation, but although a little out of scope, that extract should answer your need:

```
        $securityContext = $this->get('security.context');
        $userProvider = $this->get('fos_user.user_provider.username');
        $user = $userProvider->loadUserByUsername('alex');
        $token = new UsernamePasswordToken($user, null, 'main', array('ROLE_USER'));
        $securityContext->setToken($token);
```

Answer (score 0):

That is how I implemented it for one of projects (not with FOSUserBundle, but probably you'll find it helpful)

```php
private function createAuthorizedClient($role)
{
    $userProvider = new YourUserProvider(...);
    $user = $userProvider->createUserMethod(...);

    $client = $this->createClient(); //Normal WebTestCase client
    $client->getCookieJar()->set(new Cookie(session_name(), true));
    $session = self::$kernel->getContainer()->get('session');
    $token =  new UsernamePasswordToken($user, 'password', 'main', array($role));
    $client->getContainer()->get('security.context')->setToken($token);
    $session->set('_security_main', serialize($token));

    return $client;
}
```

Don't forget to mock expected results for user object.

Answer (score 0):

Since i cannot comment on your solution i have to create a new answer. Actually the other solutions are correct in that they use a Functional test to test a specific scenario. You are using a Unit test to test a scenario that belongs into a functional test which is why you had to hack the user login into it. Please consider the other solutions and make a functional test out of it by checking the DOM object for the correct Menu items.